# Conditonal tasks in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have an Airflow DAG that has two tasks that I only want to run if certain conditions are met. If these conditions aren't met, I'd like them skipped.

The DAG looks like this:

```
@dag(
    dag_id="id_123",
    schedule=DAG_SCHEDULE,
    start_date=days_ago(0),
    catchup=False,
    default_args={
        "retries": 0,
    },
)
def dag_runner():
    @task(task_id="get_data_src_a")
    def get_data_src_a() -> list:
        # return data from src_a

    @task(task_id="get_data_src_b")
    def get_data_src_b() -> list:
        # return data from src_b

    @task(task_id="find_uniq_users")
    def find_uniq_users(users_from_a, users_from_b) -> list:
        # return users in src_a but not in src_b

    @task(task_id="do_something_with_users")
    def do_something_with_users(uniq_users):
        # do something with unique users

    users_from_a = get_data_src_a()
    users_from_b = get_data_src_b()
    uniq_users = find_uniq_users(users_from_a,users_from_b)
    do_something_with_users(uniq_users)
```

The above code works, but I'd like to improve it. I don't want `find_uniq_users` to run if `users_from_b` is an empty list.

I also don't want `do_something_with_users` to run if `uniq_users` is empty.

I've tried the following, but it didn't appear to work:

```
if users_from_b:
   uniq_users = find_uniq_users(users_from_a, users_from_b)
else:
   uniq_users = users_from_a
if uniq_users:
   do_something_with_users(uniq_users)
```

Is anyone able to show me what I should be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [short_circuit](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-branch-operator#taskshort_circuit-shortcircuitoperator) operator/decorator that skips all downstream tasks on condition and looks like you could use it for your case.

```py
def dag_runner():
    [...]

    @task.short_circuit(task_id="should_do_something_with_users")
    def should_do_something_with_users(uniq_users):
        return uniq_users

    users_from_a = get_data_src_a()
    users_from_b = get_data_src_b()
    uniq_users = find_uniq_users(users_from_a,users_from_b)
    should_do_something_with_users(uniq_users) >> do_something_with_users(uniq_users)
```

Comment: Sorry, just realized I missed part of your question (*I don't want `find_uniq_users` to run if `users_from_b` is an empty list*) - but this should be just one more short_circuit task.